# How to remove the axis padding beneath the bars in Matplotlib 3D bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to remove the padding between the bottom of the bars in the 3D bar plot and the boundaries of the plot? My attempts to use `ax.set_zmargin(0)` or `ax.set_zlim([0, None])` have not had an impact on the result.

[image: 3D bar plot highlighting padding]

I would like there to be no extra graphed space after the '0' tick on the z-axis. The bottom z-axis grid lines should be flush with the bottom of the bars in the plot. The problem can be seen in the Matplotlib 3D bar plot demo code below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# setup the figure and axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

# fake data
_x = np.arange(4)
_y = np.arange(5)
_xx, _yy = np.meshgrid(_x, _y)
x, y = _xx.ravel(), _yy.ravel()

top = x + y
bottom = np.zeros_like(top)
width = depth = 1

ax.bar3d(x, y, bottom, width, depth, top, shade=True)
ax.set_zmargin(0)
ax.set_zlim([0, None])

plt.show()
```